# MVC3 EDMmetadata table not found

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

I am new in MVC3 i am going to create a MVC3 test project where i am create model class name WhiteAccount with ID,Name,Email,Password property. and successfully create a DB but when i add another new property in that WhiteAccount model class and in my DB table too but it give me some error. Some people say just delete the EDMmetadata table from your DB, **But Here is the problem i have no EDMmetadata table in my DB !** I create my DB by EntityFramework v4.3.1 system automatically (CodeFirst). What should i do now ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check for the __MigrationHistory table.
Open the nuget package manager console and run

```
update-database -script
```

It will likely give you a message about having to enable it first, follow those directions
Run: Enable-Migrations

some more info on migrations
http://blogs.msdn.com/b/adonet/archive/2012/02/09/ef-4-3-code-based-migrations-walkthrough.aspx

Im gathering this table is there in your db (under system tables) and it contains your model information. Since your project changed you need to tell the migrations about the new field or delete the table (__MigrationsHistory)

Comment: i did everything u told me. but i can't find the __MigrationHistory table anywhere in my DB ! but i find 201206261827557_InitialCreate.cs name file in a Migrations named folder with another file Configuration.cs . What should i do now ?

Comment: Ok i found the System Table folder :) Just i had to change the view to Object type by right clicking to my DB Connection into Server Explore.

Comment: are you all good now or..? did you try the update-database -script and run the script it generates?

Comment: Yes, Ok i did that. Thank u my friend :)